# Vue perform long lasting task on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I dont understand the right way to handle long lasting tasks/calls when binding a vue method to a Ui button click event.

I expect the following:

- If I click the button in my example, I would expect the button to be not clickable (disabled) right away, because I set the value loading to true.
- I would also expect the animation of the mouse click to be visible right after the click, not much later after the method that is triggered (doSomeTask()) is over.

But instead the button click animation and button beeing disabled appears after the execution of the long task.

What do I miss?
Is it Vue specific or just JS?

Thank you very much.

File Test.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <button  v-on:click="buttonClicked" :disabled="loading">My Button</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
          loading: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {

      buttonClicked(){
        if(!this.loading){
          this.loading = true;
          this.doSomeTask()
        }
      },

      doSomeTask(){
        console.log("task started");
        for (let i= 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
          if(i % 10000000 === 0){
            console.log(i)
          }
        }
        console.log("task over");
        //this.myLoad = false;
      }
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because javascript is a single threaded programming language. You can do one thing at the time in javascript. Because of that if you have high computed functions browser could be unreachable. You need to use backend for functions like this.

Comment: But whats is about async methods, for example with Promise? I tried adding, but did not change the behaviour. Also Vuex enables actions which are kind of asynchron. But I dont want to use Vuex.

Comment: the following article helped me understanding more about the single-threaded topic and asynchron possibilities with JS (https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/03/14/wrapping-your-head-around-async-programming/)

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {

    buttonClicked() {
      if (this.loading) return;
      this.loading = true;
      this.doSomeTask();
    },

    doSomeTask() {
      console.log("task started");
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        if (i % 10000000 === 0) {
          console.log(i)
        }
      }
      console.log("task over");
      //this.myLoad = false;
    }
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <button @click="buttonClicked">
           <loading-icon v-if="loading"></loading-icon>
           <span v-else> Your Button</span>
      </button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: hi, that does not change the descripted behaviour. Also the "loading-icon" is unknown.

Comment: Place an icon instead of loading-icon!! That was an example.

Comment: For me the solution cant be changing a button, the question is about detaching the long lasting task from the UI.